# Can a child have multiple parents in google spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I was trying out the google spanner and couldnt find in any docs about wether a child table can have multiple parent tables. I think there cannot be such a case, just wanted to make sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. An interleaved table can have only one direct parent table. However, there can be multiple levels in the [hierarchy](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-and-data-model#creating_a_hierarchy_of_interleaved_tables), so you may be able to model this differently and achieve the same result.